How can I add a dropdown menu to select which file you want to play with ruffle flash player?
So I have a website and I have a folder called "swf" with a bunch of .swf files.
What I want to do is make a webpage where you can select a file from a drop down menu and ruffle will play it.
the code to play a file using ruffle is:
<div id="container"> </div>
<script src="ruffle/ruffle.js"></script>
<script>
    window.RufflePlayer = window.RufflePlayer || {};
        window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
            const ruffle = window.RufflePlayer.newest();
            const player = ruffle.createPlayer();
            const container = document.getElementById("container"); 
            container.appendChild(player);
            player.load({
                url: "filename.swf", 
                backgroundColor: "#000", 
             });
            player.style.width = "450px"; 
            player.style.height = "450px";
        });
</script>

Sorry if my question is a bit vague.
‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ruffle Flash Player</title>
    <script src="ruffle/ruffle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <select id="fileSelector">
        <option value="file1.swf">File 1</option>
        <option value="file2.swf">File 2</option>
        <!-- Add more options for other files -->
    </select>

    <script>
        window.RufflePlayer = window.RufflePlayer || {};
        window.addEventListener("load", () => {
            const ruffle = window.RufflePlayer.newest();
            const player = ruffle.createPlayer();
            const container = document.getElementById("container");
            const fileSelector = document.getElementById("fileSelector");

            // Load the selected file when an option is chosen
            fileSelector.addEventListener("change", () => {
                const selectedFile = fileSelector.value;
                player.load({
                    url: selectedFile,
                    backgroundColor: "#000",
                });
            });

            container.appendChild(player);
            player.style.width = "450px";
            player.style.height = "450px";
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

In this example:
We’ve added a  element with options for different SWF files.
When the user selects a file from the dropdown menu, the corresponding SWF file will be loaded using Ruffle.
Remember to adjust the file names and paths (value attributes in the  tags) to match your actual SWF files. If you have more files, add additional options to the dropdown menu.
Hope this helps :)
